# " You've already purchased this In-App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, titanium, storekit

I created free Test Product and Test User in iTunes. if Move that App to ipad...when i click on product purchase button it ask Test User Details..I given those details.. But after that I got this message. I.e.

"You've already purchased this In-App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded". 
I'm working on titanium platform, using alloy frame work, ios version is 7, titanium sdk version 3.1.3 and storekit module version is 3.0.0

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem? Did you not previously make the purchase with that user?

Comment: I already purchased... but still am unable to find where my product is going to store.

Comment: Where the download is going to be saved to?

Comment: Exactly that only i don't under stand .... how can i check that..

Answer (score 0):

This is done with a combination of `SKDownload` and `TiStorekitDownload`. Once you have the download object you can check the progress and then get the `contentURL` which is the location on disk.

Comment: i applied the following code                                          if(evt.downloads){                                                   Storekit.startDownloads({                                                 downloads: evt.downloads      });